# Привязка к нажатой ссылке

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть динамическое формирование списка с ссылками:

```
 <ul class="uk-navbar-nav" id="navigation-links">
    <? foreach ($arResult["SECTIONS"] as $key => $value): ?>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="<?= $key ?>" class="menu-links"><?= $value ?></a></li>
    <? endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Также есть обработчик клика по ссылке:

```
$('#navigation-links a').on("click", function () {
     var sectionId = $(this).attr("id");
     if(sectionId == 10270) {
        //do something
     }
});
```

Проблема в том, что сейчас у меня жестко забит `id` (10270) в условии. НО это не верно, он может поменяться при формировании списка и все перестанет работать. Возможно ли каким-то образом еще привязаться к нажатой ссылке?

Comment: Условие проверяет, является ли ссылка последней нажатой?

Comment: 1) Судя по всему это не динамическое формирование; 2) Зачем вообще используется это условие, если может быть разный id?

Comment: Что такое 10270? Чем отличается от остальных id?

Comment: @Mrak, 10270 это id раздела, который сформирован на стороне битрикса. Я их вывожу на страницу. При  нажатии на любую из ссылок, происходит формирование нужных мне данных. В разделе 10270 к этим данным нужно, грубо говря, нарисовать доп. таблицу. Эта таблица не нужна в остальных разделах, только в этом.

Comment: Я не помню, можно ли в Битриксе добавить свойство разделу, например 'HaveTable'?. Можно?

Comment: @Mrak, свойства добавлять там можно, но только опять проблема, в админке данные заносят путем импорта из excel файла, и соответственно если будет не соответствие имени раздела в экселе и в админке, в админке он становится неактивным, и создается новый раздел, конечно, уже без данного свойства

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте таким образом. Тут при клике на любую ссылку сначала получаете `id` самой ссылки и объект, в котором хранятся вообще все `id` имеющихся в списке ссылок. Ну а дальше по сравнению выполняете нужный вам код. При этом айдишники будут обновляться при каждом клике на любую ссылку из списка.

```js
$('#navigation-links').on('click', 'a', function() {
    
   var sectionId = $(this).attr("id"),
       listId= {};
       
       $('li').each(function (idx, item) {
       
             listId[idx] = $('a', item).attr("id")
       });
   
   for (key in listId) {
   
    if (listId[key] == sectionId) {
    
      console.log('Открыть ссылку с id: ' + sectionId,
      '...А вот и  ключ: ' + listId[key]);
    
    }
   
   }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="uk-navbar-nav" id="navigation-links">
<li><a id='5' href='#' class="menu-links">1</a></li>
<li><a id='some-id' href='#' class="menu-links">2</a></li>
<li><a id='3' href='#' class="menu-links">[jred</a></li>
<li><a id='345345' href='#' class="menu-links">123331231</a></li>
<li><a id='44334' href='#' class="menu-links">1</a></li>
</ul>
```